# libcurl with libssh2 - one or more libs available at link-time are not available run-time

Tags: linux, debian, libcurl, libssh, libssh2

I get the following error when trying to ./configure libcurl 7.22.0

> one or more libs available at link-time are not available run-time. Libs used at link-time: -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lz

When I ./configure with **--without-libssh2** it works just fine.

Steps I have taken:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
apt-get install libssh-dev

cd /var
wget http://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.3.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf libssh2-1.3.0.tar.gz
cd libssh2-1.3.0
./configure
make
make install
```

SSL support works fine, by the way. I must have done something wrong with libssh

I have also tried:

```
./configure --with-libssh2
./configure --with-libssh2-path=/usr/local/lib
./configure --with-libssh2=/usr
./configure --with-libssh2=/usr/local/lib
```

But it didn't make a difference. I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "libssh-dev" package is completely unrelated and unnecessary since it's a different library not used by libcurl nor libssh2.

The problem you face is probably that "make install" with libssh2 installs the library /usr/local/lib by default and you have not edited /etc/ld.so.conf to load libs from that directory. Edit the file and run ldconfig (both actions as root). Alternatively, install libssh2 into another directory that already is searched in by ld.so.

Comment: ldconfig seems to have done the trick on it's own, thanks for answering.. never even heard of it before.

Answer (score 0):

check while openssl installed successly?

```
openssl version
```

if not show version info, set openssl correctly
for example:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

and continue install curl, it work for me