# configure: error: one or more libs available at link-time are not available run-time. Libs used at link-time: -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz

Tags: configure

env: centos7
install curl

when i start install curl and ./configure --with-ssl --with-zlib, i occurs errors about libs, what mean about link-time? it's env set? i have no any experience about installtaion by make, needed to install other package? how to fix it?

```
./configrue --with-ssl --with-zlib
```

accurs errors:

```
checking run-time libs availability... failed
configure: error: one or more libs available at link-time are not available 
run-time. Libs used at link-time: -lssh2  -lssl -lcrypto -lz
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libcurl with libssh2 - one or more libs available at link-time are not available run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059425/libcurl-with-libssh2-one-or-more-libs-available-at-link-time-are-not-available)

Comment: The error probably means that you need to install the missing libraries e.g. `ssh2`, `ssl` and `crypto`

Comment: i uninstall ssh2,  that's not effect for installing

Comment: i find the reason that about install oepnssl, i post answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the errors occur bebause of openssl install

after installed openssl, should check up while it usefully
when i input `openssl version`, it show same unkown path errors

so, u should set:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in front of the configure script:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64 ./configure --with-ssl --with-zlib`